# Porting WinForms Application to Mac OS

Tags: c#, winforms, macos, mono

I have written a C#/WinForms application in Visual Studio. From my research I'm gathering that it is possible to make a Mac-friendly version of my application using Mono, but I don't understand the process. Can someone explain how to go about making a Mac OS version of a WinForms application, and exactly what role Mono plays in it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are plenty of guides/explanations out there,

- [What is Mono](http://mono-project.com/What_is_Mono)
- [Porting Winforms Applications to run on Mac OS](http://mono-project.com/Guide%3a_Porting_Winforms_Applications)

Comment: The second link was what I was looking for; I'm not sure how I didn't see it beforehand. Sorry for the unnecessary question.

Answer (score 0):

Imho, the most appropriate solution is to use Silverlight out of browser application. It works fine on Mac OS. I created several applications using this technique.

Comment: No more Silverlight. "In 2012 Microsoft deprecated Silverlight for HTML5 in Windows 8." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight