# C# windows application run in MacOS

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I'm just new in C# Windows Form. Now I have a project that Uploads a txt file and output into a PDF file. Now I need to use C# windows form for this but I'm just curious if I develop this using C# Windows form will I be able to install the application on a MacOS environment and use it as how I can use it on windows? Are there any consideration needed? Like do I need to install a certain package just to make it work in Mac or vice versa?

Comment: [Even WinForms for .NET Core isn't cross-platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/winforms).

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/53466621/2932052

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm just new in C# Windows Form.

Hi!

> Now I have a project that Uploads a txt file and output into a PDF file.

Go on...

> Now I need to use C# windows form for this

No, you **don't** need to use WinForms to simply upload a text file and download a PDF.

> but I'm just curious if I develop this using C# Windows form will I be able to install the application on a MacOS environment and use it as how I can use it on windows?

No, you cannot. WinForms is tightly coupled to the Microsoft Windows operating-system (the biggest clue is in the name: **Windows** Forms. WinForms' is a thin wrapper around Windows' default windowed controls and widgets (also called User32 and Common Controls) as well as OLE, COM + ActiveX, and other Windows-centric APIs.

[There are attempts](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/) to make a subset of WinForms work on other operating systems, but because WinForms is not natively cross-platform you won't have things like support for macOS's main menu and your users will be able to tell that your program doesn't *look and feel* like a native program.

> Are there any consideration needed? Like do I need to install a certain package just to make it work in Mac or vice versa?

No, it won't work.

### Alternative Approaches:

- Make your application using WinForms `System.Windows.Forms` and make it available to macOS users through some form of application remoting:

  - Run it on a Windows box accessed using macOS' Remote Desktop app.
  - Run it on a Windows box accessed using a browser-based RDP gateway.
  - Run it in a Windows virtual-machine running on an Apple Mac (Parallels Fusion, VirtualBox, etc).
- Using only natively supported cross-platform features in .NET Core:

  - Make your application with a built-in `http://localhost` ASP.NET web-server that hosts a GUI web-application accessed with a web-browser that interacts with the rest of your application code.
  - Make a command-line only application.
  - Make a text-mode GUI application using a library like `ncurses` for .NET.
- Make a platform-specific GUI while still sharing the rest of your application code (e.g. using Xamarin to use Cocoa from .NET, use WinForms or WPF on Windows, GTK# for Linux/BSD, etc).

Comment: Might be worth noting .NET 5 will have some level of WinForms support (and will be cross platform): https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-preview-1/#:~:text=NET%205.%20.,that%20is%20higher%20than%20both%20.

Comment: @jslowik The .NET 5 runtime is cross-platform, yes - but WinForms is just one component of .NET's greater class-library which is not included in the cross-platform part. That blog article doesn't say anything about WinForms being made available on other platforms - and I think it would be impossible to anyway, because things like `Control.Handle` become meaningless, for example.

Comment: Good call out, @Dai. I think I just wanted it to be true!

Comment: @Dai thanks for the reply as a followup question will I still be able to use C# to develop an application to work both for Windows and Mac?

Comment: @MadzQuestioning .net core is now available to develop console application both Mac & Windows too. But Winform is not, even it could be developed with .net core, but these components are not support.

Comment: @TấnNguyên thanks make sense now.

Comment: @MadzQuestioning That depends if you want to make a non-browser-based GUI application using  or a command-line application. Currently only command-line applications are cross-platform - but you can build a browser-based GUI using a built-in web-server using ASP.NET, for example. **You can** build a platform-specific GUI for macOS in C#/.NET though, but by using Xamarin: https://www.jenx.si/2020/01/15/how-to-start-developing-macos-applications-with-csharp/

Comment: @MadzQuestioning I've amended my answer with a listing of alternatives.

Comment: @Dai thanks really appreciate your help will accept it as solution